# axon 3.4 CommandHandler in Aggregate not being triggered when command is sent from external service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, event-sourcing, axon

so I'm trying to get my head around the distributed command bus in axon 3.4.
I have a use-case that when a certain command gets send an aggregate sends an event that starts a saga, this saga sends 2 commands to keep the data send to 2 different services in a consistent state.

Now here come's the tricky part, the CommandHandlers are defined in external services that do something and then send a command back with the result of the operation in it. However when the command gets send I always end up with a timeout exception, so the CommandBus knows which aggregate has to handle it but can't assign the correct Aggregate to the Command.

Currently commandService.createCurrency only logs a message, that's why there's a Thread.sleep in the event handler, to simulate a longer running process.

Below you'll find my code:

```
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Registration registration;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Bean
    public CommandBusConnector springHttpCommandBusConnector(@Qualifier("localSegment") CommandBus localSegment,
                                                             Serializer serializer) {
        return new SpringHttpCommandBusConnector(localSegment, restTemplate, serializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandRouter springCloudCommandRouter(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
        return new SpringCloudCommandRouter(discoveryClient, registration, new AnnotationRoutingStrategy());
    }

    @Primary // to make sure this CommandBus implementation is used for autowiring
    @Bean
    public DistributedCommandBus springCloudDistributedCommandBus(CommandRouter commandRouter,
                                                                  CommandBusConnector commandBusConnector) {
        return new DistributedCommandBus(commandRouter, commandBusConnector);
    }

}
```

#### Service 1

Aggregate:

```
@Aggregate
@Data
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class CreateCurrencyAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

    @CommandHandler
    public CreateCurrencyAggregate(CreateCurrencyCommand command) {
        log.info("starting create currency");
        Assert.notNull(command.getId(), "CreateCurrencyCommand must have an id");
        Assert.hasLength(command.getId(), "CreateCurrencyCommand id cannot be an empty String");
        this.id = command.getId();
        apply(CreateCurrencyEvent.builder()
                .id(command.getId())
                .payload(command.getPayload())
                .build());
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void on(DalCreatedCommand command) {
        log.info("Currency created on dal layer");
        apply(DalCurrencyCreatedEvent.builder()
                .dalId(command.getId())
                .build());

    }
}
```

Saga:

```
@Slf4j
@Saga
public class CreateCurrencySaga {

    @Autowired
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "id")
    public void handle(CreateCurrencyEvent event) {
        log.info("starting saga...");
        dalCreated = false;
        as400Created = true;
        SagaLifecycle.associateWith("id", event.getId());
        SagaLifecycle.associateWith("dalId", event.getId());
        commandGateway.send(CreateDalCurrencyCommand.builder()
                .id(event.getId())
                .payload(event.getPayload())
                .build());
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "dalId")
    public void handle(DalCurrencyCreatedEvent event) {
        log.info("receiving createdEvent");
        SagaLifecycle.end();
    }


}
```

#### Service 2

External CommandHandler

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Component
public class CurrencyCommandHandler {

    @Autowired
    private EventBus eventBus;

    @CommandHandler
    public void on(CreateDalCurrencyCommand command) {
        eventBus.publish(asEventMessage(CreateDalCurrencyEvent.builder()
                .id(command.getId())
                .payload(command.getPayload())
                .build()));
    }
}
```

Eventhandler

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CurrencyEventHandlers {

    private final CurrencyCommandService commandService;

    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @EventHandler
    public void handle(CreateDalCurrencyEvent event){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        commandService.createCurrency(event.getId(), event.getPayload());
        var result = commandGateway.send(DalCreatedCommand.builder()
            .id(event.getId())
            .build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can give you some added background in this area.

The implementation of Spring Cloud used as the Discovery Service makes a world of difference, sadly.
Internally, the `SpringCloudCommandRouter` uses the Metadata of a `ServiceInstance` to share the `MessageRoutingInformation`. Every application connected to your set up will be represented by a `ServiceInstance`, so sharing which messages (thus also commands) you as a service can handle through this approach would be simple.

When the `SpringCloudCommandRouter` was built however, this was tested by utilizing Eureka as the Spring Cloud implementation. Eureka allows adjusting the metadata of a `ServiceInstance`, so I can state with fair confidence that if you're using Spring Cloud Eureka, that I'd expect things to work as it does.

However, if you'd for example be using Consul, it's a different story.
Spring Cloud Consul does not allow adjusting the metadata of a `ServiceInstance`. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/204) in the past to adjust the API to actually be specific about being able to update the metadata.

Regardless, the issue with providing support for Spring Cloud Consul, and other implementations which do not allow adjusting the metadata, has been covered by Axon Framework by providing the `SpringCloudHttpBackupCommandRouter`.

I'd thus suggest to adjust your configuration into using a  `SpringCloudHttpBackupCommandRouter` instead of the ``SpringCloudCommandRouter`